# tar processing files multiple times with find -newer

Tags: find, tar, sort, xargs, uniq

I'm trying to use tar(1) to create an archive of files newer than a specific file (`fileA`). However, when I use find(1) to obtain the list of files to pass to tar, some files are listed multiple times:

```
$ touch fileA
$ mkdir test
$ touch test/{fileB,fileC}
$ tar -c -v $(find test -newer fileA) > test.tar
test/
test/fileC
test/fileB
test/fileC
test/fileB
```

Using xargs(1) to pass the list of files to tar results in similar behavior:

```
$ find test -newer fileA | xargs tar -c -v > test.tar
test/
test/fileC
test/fileB
test/fileC
test/fileB
```

Using sort(1) and uniq(1) to remove duplicates doesn't work either:

```
$ find test -newer fileA | sort | uniq | xargs tar -c -v > test.tar
test/
test/fileC
test/fileB
test/fileB
test/fileC
```

Is there a way for tar to only include each file newer than `fileA` once?

**Edit:** I'm specifically looking for a solution that doesn't involve GNU extensions to tar (for example, which would work with [suckless tar](https://git.suckless.org/sbase/file/tar.c.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find test -newer fileA
```

finds the `test` directory as well as the individual files therein, so `tar` adds `test` (and all its contents), then `test/fileB` and `test/fileC`.

Tighten your `find` to avoid this:

```
tar -c -v $(find test -type f -newer fileA) > test.tar
```

Note that using command substitution in this way can cause issues *e.g.* with filenames containing spaces or wildcards; to avoid that, use

```
find test -type f -newer fileA -print0 | tar -c -v --null -T- -f - > test.tar
```

(with GNU `find` and `tar`), or

```
find test -type f -newer fileA -exec tar cvf - {} + > test.tar
```

(assuming you don’t have too many files to archive).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
tar --newer=fileA cvf test.tar test
```

Comment: That command gives `tar: Substituting -9223372036854775807 for unknown date format 'fileA'`. I guess that `fileA` modification time could be extracted and passed to `--newer` option to GNU tar, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve GNU extensions to tar. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Vilinkameni, `tar` is not a standard command, all implementations are different and mostly incompatible between each other.

Comment: I never said it is, just that I want to avoid options specific to GNU tar. I updated my question to reflect that. The options supported by suckless tar are a subset of the options of GNU tar, however, and I suspect also a subset of some other variants of tar.